# Java Swing - Working with Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I made a simple click test application (You may have seen some on the web, you have a big button. Once you click on it, a 10 seconds timer is started and the goal is to click the most times on the button) I tough it was a good way to practice both `Swing` `API` and basic `threads`. It's just basic stuff, I know I can use an `API` as a timer and stuff, but let's keep it simple for now.

The problem seems to be that I can't modify a `JLabel` Inside the `setTime()` method, which is called from the `Thread` Inside the `Timer` `class`.

Here is the `Main` `class`:

```
package com.tremblayalex.clicktest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Initialize Variables
    private final JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    private JLabel topText = new JLabel();
    private JButton btnClick = new JButton();
    private int clicks = 0;
    private boolean isStarted = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Main()
    {
        if (!isStarted)
        {
            initComponents();
            registerEvents();
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Initialize Components
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private void initComponents() 
    {
        // JFrame Settings
        setTitle("Input Box");
        setSize(1000, 400);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        add(contentPane);

        // Content Pane (BorderLayout)
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.add(topText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPane.add(btnClick, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Top Text
        topText.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        topText.setText("Click to Start");

        // Button Click
        btnClick.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
        btnClick.setText("CLICK TO START");

    }


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Register Events
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private void registerEvents() 
    {
        btnClick.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                if (isStarted == false)
                {
                    isStarted = true;
                    new Thread(new Timer()).start();
                }

                clicks++;
                btnClick.setText("[Clicks] " + clicks);

            }
        });

    }




    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Getters and Setters
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public void setTime(double time)
    {
        System.out.println(time);
        topText.setText("Time: " + time);

        if (time >= 10)
        {
            if (clicks < 50)
            {
                topText.setText("Your average CPS is " + (clicks / 10) + "." + " Try to do better next time!");
            } else if (clicks >= 50 || clicks < 100){
                topText.setText("Your average CPS is " + (clicks / 10) + "." + " You are in the average!");
            } else if (clicks >= 100 || clicks < 150){
                topText.setText("Your average CPS is " + (clicks / 10) + "." + " You click very fast!");
            } else if (clicks >= 150 || clicks < 250){
                topText.setText("Your average CPS is " + (clicks / 10) + "." + " Clicking is your destiny!");
            } else if (clicks >= 250){
                topText.setText("Your average CPS is " + (clicks / 10) + "." + " Hack? :D");
            } else {
                topText.setText("Your average CPS is " + (clicks / 10) + "." + " Internal Error.");
            }

            isStarted = false;

            btnClick.setText("CLICK TO RESTART");
        }
    }


}
```

And this is the `Timer` `class`:

```
package com.tremblayalex.clicktest;

public class Timer implements Runnable
{   
    private final Main main = new Main();

    public void run()
    {
        for (double time = 0; time <= 10; time += 0.1)
        {
            main.setTime(time);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {}
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

Thank you for your help, I made a new version using `Timer`:

```
package com.tremblayalex.clicktest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Initialize Variables
    private final JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    private JLabel topText = new JLabel();
    private JButton btnClick = new JButton();
    private JButton btnRestart = new JButton();
    private double clicks = 0;
    private double time;
    private boolean isStarted = false;


    private Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent paramActionEvent) 
        {
            if (time < 100)
            {
                time++;
                topText.setText("Time: " + (time / 10));    
            } 
            else {

                if (clicks < 50)
                {
                    topText.setText("Your average CPS is " + (clicks / 10) + "  Try to do better next time!");
                } else if (clicks >= 50 && clicks < 100){
                    topText.setText("Your average CPS is " + (clicks / 10) + "  You are in the average!");
                } else if (clicks >= 100 && clicks < 150){
                    topText.setText("Your average CPS is " + (clicks / 10) + "  You click very fast!");
                } else if (clicks >= 150 && clicks < 250){
                    topText.setText("Your average CPS is " + (clicks / 10) + "  Clicking is your destiny!");
                } else if (clicks >= 250){
                    topText.setText("Your average CPS is " + (clicks / 10) + "  Hack? :D");
                } else {
                    topText.setText("Your average CPS is " + (clicks / 10) + "  Internal Error.");
                }

                timer.stop();

                isStarted = false;
                btnClick.setEnabled(false);
                btnRestart.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Main()
    {
        initComponents();
        registerEvents();
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Initialize Components
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private void initComponents() 
    {
        // JFrame Settings
        setTitle("Click Test");
        setSize(1000, 400);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        add(contentPane);

        // Content Pane (BorderLayout)
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.add(topText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPane.add(btnClick, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(btnRestart, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // Top Text
        topText.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        topText.setText("Click to Start");

        // Button Click
        btnClick.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
        btnClick.setText("CLICK TO START");

        // Button Restart
        btnRestart.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        btnRestart.setText("Restart");
        btnRestart.setEnabled(false);

    }


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Register Events
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private void registerEvents() 
    {
        btnClick.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                if (isStarted == false)
                {
                    isStarted = true;
                    clicks = 0;
                    time = 0;
                    topText.setText("Time: " + time);

                    timer.start();
                }



                clicks++;
                btnClick.setText("[Clicks] " + (int)clicks);

            }
        });


        btnRestart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {

                btnClick.setEnabled(true);
                btnClick.setText("CLICK TO RESTART");
                btnRestart.setEnabled(false);

            }
        });

    }


}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to use threads directly here, but instead simply use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead. It's much cleaner and **much** safer.

Comment: Basically, especially as a newbie, never ever call Thread.sleep() or Thread.yield().  Especially never sleep on the [EDT (Swing thread).](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)  Look at using [java.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [java.util.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) instead.

Comment: @markspace: no, definitely **not** `java.util.Timer` here since this is a Swing application. The utility Timer will almost be guaranteed to cause intermittent threading exceptions.

Comment: java.util.Timer would work fine if the result doesn't need to be run on the EDT.  If he's going to do something else, for example to test a file, it's fine.

Comment: @markspace: we already know that he wants to modify a JLabel's state while counting down, so again I stand by what I stated previously.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that's fair.  Specifically for modifying a JLabel a Swing Timer is probably better (it could be done with a regular timer but you'd have to use `invokeLater()` or a similar method for running code on the EDT).

Comment: According to the Edit, should I add something to make it perfect? I guess I should add an `EventQueue.invokeLater`, but else then that, is it good? I'm still open to improving.

Comment: See [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and maybe add an [RSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetitive_strain_injury) warning.

Comment: Alex: yes, a CardLayout